# Трафик в VBox'a

Tags: linux, windows, virtualbox, wireshark

Есть запущенная виртуальная машина(Linux) на VBox'e, по умолчанию она настроена в NAT. Есть ли возможность определить какие делает запросы(порты, сайты и т.п., то есть просмотреть весь трафик) в интернет и делает ли вообще? Войти в виртуальную машину нет возможности.

Comment: Виртуалбокс создает свое сетевое подключение?

Comment: может быть wireshark?

Comment: eri - в сетевых подключениях есть VirtualBox Host-Only Network и его отключая всё равно интернет в виртуальной машине(Linux) работает.  Pavel Gridin - тоже думаю об этом. Просто задал этот вопрос по трафику ибо не знаю теории в этой части. Стоит ли вообще "копать" или нет, чтоб точно увидеть и знать что машина делает то что надо и ни какие левые запросы не отправляет. Хоть ей доступна только одна общая папка и всё.